# asp.net reference required to assembly system.webapplication.services

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In visual studio 2013, I got an error like Reference required to assembly 'System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version =4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKey token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' containing the type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser'.Add one to your project.

The same code doesn't appear an error in VS 2010 (i guess VS is using asp.net 2.0?)

I know some reference is missing? But I don't know the exact file (if there is any ) that I should add to reference?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to `System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll` for .net 4.0

It is in the docs!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.aspx

Comment: thank you, but for some reason, I can't add it? The dll file is under my .net framework 4.5, but I can't add it to the reference (by ticking the box left to System.Web.ApplicationServices) and click OK?

Answer (score 0):

```
Right Click => Add Reference => .NET tab =>
```

here you will see all the list of `dlls` , look for `System. . . .` and get your required reference and hit ok button